# Filter a list of Generic Type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method which returns a list of Generic Type

```
List<T> GetResultList<T>()
```

T is class. For each class, there is a member Date. Now, I want to filter the list of T in GetResultList by Date. Is it possible?

Or, I have to do this in each class?

What's more is that in different classes, the member should be used in filter are different, i.e. for class1, I want to filter Date, for class2, I want to filter Date2. Could this be done in GetResultList instead of each class?

Thanks

Comment: "For each class, there is a member Date": is that just happenstance or do they derive from a common class or interface? In other words, you're telling us but are you telling the compiler?

Comment: If you have 2 classes and 2 different criteria, why do you want to use generics?

Comment: Look into iFilter https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692577(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If they're different classes, how are you returning them in one list? Do they all derive from a common base class or implement the same interface?

Answer (score 1):

## Options to filter a known field

(a) Best option: create an interface describing the contract (e.g. presence of a `Date` property) and constraint your generic type to that.
This option has the benefit of being statically typed: using a `T` that doesn't implement the interface is a compile-time error.

```
interface IDated 
{
  DateTime Date { get; } 
}

List<T> GetResultList<T>() where T: IDated
{
  T x;
  if (x.Date == DateTime.Today); // You can access T.Date
}
```

(b) All other solutions would be run-time dynamic access. Starting with `dynamic` of course, or using reflection to access a member by name. They all have the drawback of not being verified for correctness at compile-time (i.e. using a `T` without `Date` fails at runtime) and a performance overhead.

## Options to filter an "unknown" field

> the member should be used in filter are different

(a) unify them with a consistent interface and use option (a) above.

(b) pass the field name to your dynamic or reflection-based code.

(c) pass a predicate, like the LINQ `Where` method works. Something like:

```
List<T> GetResultList<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
  T x;
  if (predicate(x)) /*...*/;
}

// Usage:
GetResultList<MyObject>(x => x.Date == DateTime.Today);
```

**EDIT:** If you don't want to code the *condition* at caller site, you can pass a value extractor (projection/like `Select`):

```
List<T> GetResultList<T>(Func<T, DateTime> getDate)
{
  T x;
  if (getDate(x) == DateTime.Today) /*...*/;
}

// Usage:
GetResultList<MyObject>(x => x.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that anything that T can represent will have a property called Date, then you could implement and interface IHasDate (or whatever)... Then if you included a condition on your generic argument anything passed in will have the T property available to it.

Untested code...

```
public interface IHasDate
{
    DateTime Date { get; }
}

public List<T> GetResultsList<T>()
    where T : IHasDate
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    //Fill list
    list.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.Date.CompareTo(t2.Date));
    Return t;
}
```

Comment: I immediately had this same thought, but OP says the date fields to compare are different (e.g. Date vs. Date2) in each type.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after typing out all that code on my phone!  in which case, perhaps just implement IComparer(T) instead and do the sorting in the class

Answer (score 0):

Pass a delegate:

```
GetResultList(x => x.Date2);
```

And update your `GetResultList` function to use that delegate:

```
List<T> GetResultList<T>(Func<T, Date> dateGetter)
{
    return someList.OrderBy(x => dateGetter(x)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** 
Since you speak about `List<T>` all objects in the list already have an interface - T The **classic solution would be to implement special method inside the classes** (here `T` is `IClassWithDate`):

```
public interface IClassWithDate
{
    DateTime DateForFiltering();
}

internal class classDerrivedFromInterface1 : IClassWithDate
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public int AnotherField;

    public DateTime DateForFiltering()
    {
        return Date;
    }
}

internal class classDerivvedFromInterface2 : IClassWithDate
{
    public DateTime Date2;
    public int AnotherField;

    public DateTime DateForFiltering()
    {
        return Date2;
    }
}
public List<IClassWithDate> GetResultList<IClassWithDate>()
{               
    var listOfIClassesWithDate = new List<IClassWithDate> { new classDerrivedFromInterface1 { Date = DateTime.MinValue, AnotherField = 2 }, new classDerivvedFromInterface2 { Date2 = DateTime.MinValue, AnotherField = 2 } };
    return listOfSimpleClasses.Where(x => x.DateForFiltering() == DateTime.MinValue).ToList();
}
```

**2)** But since you don't want to implementany logic inside classes, you can use another approach - **use dynamis**:

```
class simpleClass1
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public int AnotherField;
}

class simpleClass2
{
    public DateTime Date2;
    public int AnotherField;
}

public List<dynamic> GetResultList()
{               
        var listOfSimpleClasses = new List<dynamic> {new simpleClass1 {Date = DateTime.MinValue, AnotherField = 2}, new simpleClass2 {Date2 = DateTime.MinValue, AnotherField = 2}};
        return listOfSimpleClasses.Where(x =>
        {
            if (x is simpleClass2)
                return x.Date2 == DateTime.MinValue;
            if (x is simpleClass1)
                return x.Date == DateTime.MinValue;
            return false;
        }).ToList();
```

**3)** the same as 2nd but without dynamics (thats why this way is better then 2). You should use **type cast and object**:

```
class simpleClass1
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public int AnotherField;
}

class simpleClass2
{
    public DateTime Date2;
    public int AnotherField;
}

public List<object> GetResultList()
{                           
    var listOfObjects = new List<object>{new simpleClass1 {Date = DateTime.MinValue, AnotherField = 2},new simpleClass2 {Date2 = DateTime.MinValue, AnotherField = 2}};
    return listOfSimpleClasses.Where(x =>
    {
        if (x is simpleClass2)
            return (x as simpleClass2).Date2 == DateTime.MinValue;
        if (x is simpleClass1)
            return (x as simpleClass1).Date == DateTime.MinValue;
        return false;
    }).ToList();
}
```